# Fixing java errors and getting user input

Tags: java

Can Somebody make this work? I have minimal java knowledge and want to get a script that will run a word through the same hashing as a program and see if i can get similar results from the same code. Java..

```
import java.util.List;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
/*
BASIC FORMAT OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE SOMEONE TO FIX
ONLY WANT TO ENCRYPT VIA THIS METHOD*/


public class encrypt {
   /* WANT TO GET USER-INPUT AND RUN IT THROUGH THIS METHOD OF HASHING*/
    String code = array[0];
    String encrypted = encrypt(code);
/*ERRORS SO*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       /* WANT TO PRINT OUT RESULT HERE
        AIM IS TO GET A HASH THAT LOOKS LIKE:
        "2473511743116990591436219521516221715316",
          "101208251115150352340242201171221515066157"
        FROM THE WORD "pizzaroma"*/
        System.out.println(encrypted);
    }

    /*NO CLUE WHAT THIS DOES ^^^^ Array?*/
    private String getString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            byte b = bytes[i];
            sb.append(0xFF & b);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt(String source) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(source.getBytes());
            return getString(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
    /*FAR:encrypt.java:6:error:cannot find symbol

        String code=array[0];

        symbol:variable array

        location:*/

/*
class encrypt

encrypt.java:35:error:non-static variable encrypted cannot be
        referenced from a static context

        System.out.println(encrypted);^

        2 errors*/
```

Comment: at first i´d try to properly indent your code... it´s unreadable as it is.

Comment: MD5 is a Cryptographic hash function, not encryption.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Test {

    String code = null;
    String encrypted = null;

    private String getString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        {
            byte b = bytes[i];
            sb.append(0xFF & b);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt(String source) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(source.getBytes());
            return getString(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test t = new Test();
        t.code = "pizzaroma";

        t.encrypted = t.encrypt(t.code);

        System.out.println(t.encrypted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the help of base64 lib, first you need to import it like

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

And then change your Class to use the BASE64 class.
here some example code:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Test".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));
```